# GCR service account has admin privileges

Tags: google-cloud-platform, containers, cloud-security

Cannot use more granular roles to google managed container registry account - service-[PROJECT_NUMBER]@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com. Not sure if anyone can shed some lights on this.

It seems this service account is assigned with a primitive role "editor" by default when you enable google container registry API and you cannot change it to something more granular like cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com

Google's doc on cloudbuild
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/securing-builds/set-service-account-permissions

But not much info on container registry
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview

Our compliance tool picked up editor role are used by GCR service account. This is too much permission for just GCR access.